# Specifying EclipseLink MOXy as JAXB Provider not working

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, moxy

I'm having some problems specifying my JAXB provider when using IntelliJ with Maven.

My main goal is to use MOXy's `XmlPath` annotation so the first steps I took were to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html) in order to change my JAXB provider.

It is specified that to change your JAXB provider you need to add a `jaxb.properties` file in the same package as your class.

However when running my example:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;

@XmlRootElement(name = "debug")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Debug {
    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    @XmlPath("debug")
    private Collection<String> values = new LinkedList<>();

    public Collection<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(Collection<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        System.out.println(org.eclipse.persistence.Version.getVersion());
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Debug.class).getClass());
    }
}
```

with this pom.xml:
    
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <groupId>debug</groupId>
    <artifactId>debug</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I still see the output:

```
2.5.0
class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl`
```

I believe the first line confirms that MOXy is on my class path but I'd expected the second line to  be:

```
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
```

Just to clarify my `jaxb.properties` file is in the top level package with `Debug.java` and contains the following line:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

I'd really appreciate someone pointing out what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Thanks! Putting it in the correct directory structure in resources worked perfectly.

Comment: Use it as a System property, if it is cumbersome to add jaxb.properties files for each and every java packages where JAXB pojo classes are present. 

    System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory", "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");